# converting this function from Javascript to jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've tried over and over to change this function to jQuery but I can't seem to get it to run properly. Could anyone give me any help with it at all?

```
window.onresize = resizeImage;

function resizeImage(){
    var newHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    var newWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    document.getElementById('crofthouse').width = (newHeight / 2) * 1.33;
    document.getElementById('crofthouse').height = (newHeight / 2);
    document.getElementById('main').style.width = (newHeight / 2) * 1.33;
    document.getElementById('main').style.height = (newHeight / 2);

    var margin = (newHeight - document.getElementById('crofthouse').height) / 2;
    document.getElementById('main').style.margin = margin + ',auto,' + margin + ',auto';
}
```

here's my attempt at converting it 
window.onresize = resizeImage;

```
function resizeImage(){
var newHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
var newWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;

$("#crofthouse").css("width, (newHeight /2) * 1.33")
$("#crofthouse").css("hegiht, (newHeight /2)")
$("#main").css("width, (newHeight /2) * 1.33")
$("#main").css("height, (newHeight /2)")


var margin = (newHeight - $('#crofthouse').css("height) / 2");
$('main').css("margin = margin + ',auto,' + margin + ',auto'");

}
```

Comment: document.getElementById("sth") could be replaced by $("#sth") that is a first change. What do you mean by it doesn't run properly?

Comment: What does your best attempt look like (post in your question)?

Comment: CSS doesn't "understand" JavaScript. `document.getElementById('crofthouse').width = ...` should go to `$("#crofthouse").css("width", (newHeight /2) * 1.33)`. Note the quote placement. Also, consider using the mutli-CSS selector or chaining or using a variable to avoid re-created a jQuery (re-evaulating a selector) each time. `var house = $(#"crofthouse"); ... house.css(...)`. That will also help reduce errors like `$("main")`

Comment: You do realize that the resulting jQuery approach will run slower than the straight js approach. jQuery is a library wrapped on top of javascript, which means a well written function will do the same thing as jQuery does in the *mystical forest before it spits out it's magic*, but without all of the overhead. What you want is to keep your original function with a few updates. I will post.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it ..

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    var doc = $(document),
        croft = $('#crofthouse'),
        main = $('#main'),
        height = doc.height(),
        margin = croft.height() / 2;


    croft.add(main).css({
             width:(height / 2) * 1.33, 
             height:(height / 2)
    });
    main.css({ margin: margin + 'px auto' });
});
```

Comment: I tried this and it never worked.. do i need to change my window.onresize = resizeImage;

Comment: @user, this code should replace the whole of the code you posted in your question .. both the function and the event binding.. (*it does it all*)

Answer (score 2):

```
window.onresize = resizeImage;

function resizeImage(){
    var newHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    var newWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    var croftHouse = document.getElementById('crofthouse');
    croftHouse.height = (newHeight / 2) * 1.33;
    croftHouse.width = (newWidth / 2);
    var main = document.getElementById('main');
    main.style.width = (newHeight / 2) * 1.33;
    main.style.height = (newHeight / 2);

    var margin = (newHeight - croftHouse.height) / 2;
    main.style.margin = margin + ',auto,' + margin + ',auto';
}
```

or if you ***really*** want a jquery approach;

```
$(window).resize(resizeImage);
    function resizeImage(){
        var newHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
        var newWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
        var croftHouse = document.getElementById('crofthouse');
        croftHouse.height = (newHeight / 2) * 1.33;
        croftHouse.width = (newWidth / 2);
        var main = document.getElementById('main');
        main.style.width = (newHeight / 2) * 1.33;
        main.style.height = (newHeight / 2);

        var margin = (newHeight - croftHouse.height) / 2;
        main.style.margin = margin + ',auto,' + margin + ',auto';
    }
```

and for the record i'm not sure what `croftHouse.height` does.. did you mean `croftHouse.style.height`??

Answer (score 0):

It should work, try it.

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    var docEl = document.documentElement;
    var newHeight = docEl.clientHeight;
    var newWidth = docEl.clientWidth;
    $('#crofthouse').width((newHeight / 2) * 1.33);
    $('#crofthouse').height((newHeight / 2));
    $('#main').css({
        width: (newHeight / 2) * 1.33,
        height: newHeight / 2 
    );

    var margin = newHeight - (($('#crofthouse').height()) / 2);
    $('#main').css('margin', margin + ', auto, ' + margin + ', auto');
};
```

Comment: I wonder why do you want to convert working JavaScript to jQuery. It will always be slower than native.

Comment: Yes, but may not work cross-browser. One of the biggest advantages of using jQuery for even simple things like this is that you have a team of JS experts making everything work across different browsers seamlessly. And most of the jQuery functions delegate as quickly as possible to native JS functions if they are present.